# My EditText keeps getting censored when i tried to get its value

Tags: java, android, xml

I've created a view that accountable for the login system but I need to pass the email from EditText to my PHP using Volley request. But, it kept getting censored value of EditText whenever I tried to log the EditText value to the console and this is what i get on the log (see "Email" part). The Email log, should display inputted email.

```
2023-12-18 10:52:47.415 27950-27950 FirebaseAuth            com.example.design                   D  Notifying id token listeners about user ( oNstv5MY4eNyhz44b21qLNFEYsR2 ).
2023-12-18 10:52:47.416 27950-27950 EMAIL:                  com.example.design                   D  ***************
2023-12-18 10:52:47.417 27950-27950 FirebaseAuth            com.example.design                   I  Logging in as *************** with empty reCAPTCHA token
2023-12-18 10:52:47.422 27950-28619 System                  com.example.design                   W  Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
```

This is the java code I use to get my inputted email, I use similar code in another file for sign up process, but I can log the inputted email without censor.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

                email_in = findViewById(R.id.email);
                String email = email_in.getText().toString();

                if (email.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Please write down your email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                Log.d( "EMAIL: ", String.valueOf(email));

                pass_in = findViewById(R.id.password);
                String password = pass_in.getText().toString();

//              LOGIN MECHANISM HERE

};
```

And this is the XML for the EditText:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="10sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="E-mail"
                android:inputType="text" />
```

I tried to find any solution and none of them works. Hope i can find the answer here.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _it kept failing_ Can you [edit] your post and provide more details as to how it failed? Did you get an error? Did you get the wrong result?

Comment: @Abra there is no error but I can't get my inputted email to send it out to my API. I tried to see what the data has been sent to the API, it received ********** instead of the email

Answer (score 0):

Write `email_in = findViewById(R.id.email);` and `pass_in = findViewById(R.id.password);` in onCreate method. Hope this will solve your problem.